# is it possible to change the icon after start in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program that I want the icon to change depending on which area of the app you open.
So the default icon would be a rainbow.
if you click the green button the icon changes to green.
if you click blue it changes blue.
Simple if possible but I can't find any solution out there, I only find answers to how to change the default icon.

```
public static Scene scene;
public static Stage stage1;
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    scene = new Scene(loadFXML("ChooseYourColor"));
    stage.setTitle("Rainbow-window");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage1 = stage;
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(TBA.class.getResourceAsStream("RainbowIcon.png")));
    stage.show();
}
static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
    scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
}
private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
    return fxmlLoader.load();
}
```

```
@FXML
protected void ChangeBlue() throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("Blue-Window");
        Stage primStage = App.stage1;
        primStage.setTitle("Blue");
        primStage.getIcons().add(new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("BlueIcon.png")));
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java Swing/AWT you can set the icon at any point in time on the root level component using https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImage(java.awt.Image). I'm pretty sure a similar call exists for JavaFX.

Comment: Instead of `stage.getIcons().add` use `stage.getIcons().setAll`.   I didn’t try it, but should work.

Comment: That what `setAll` does, it replaces what was there with something new, that is, it changes it.  Try it.  See the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#setAll(E...)).

Comment: @jewelsea sorry I commented before trying I figured it out, thank you for the help, I answered the question below, and I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was I made a collection of Images called iconsList in main adding the images with

```
iconsList.add(new Image(TBA.class.getResourceAsStream("Logo.png")));
iconsList.add(new Image(TBA.class.getResourceAsStream("AMFLogo.png")));
```

then in start I did setAll and it takes index 0 as the initial

```
stage.getIcons().setAll(iconsList);
```

Then on a button call, I changed it with

```
primStage.getIcons().set(0, App.iconsList.get(1));
```

Hope this can help someone else

Comment: The icons are supposed to be icons for different scales. So you shouldn't setAll if they're different icons. There is no guarantee of which on will be shown. I am guessing all of your icons are the same size, so it probably takes the first one for the size it needs.